# How to persist the list which we made dynamically from dataFrame in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
 def getAnimalName(dataFrame: DataFrame): List[String] = {
    dataFrame.select("animal").
      filter(col("animal").isNotNull && col("animal").notEqual("")).
      rdd.map(r => r.getString(0)).distinct().collect.toList
  }
```

I am basicaly Calling this function 2 times For getting the list for different purposes . I just want to know is there a way to retain the list in memory and we dont have to call the same function again and again to generate the list and only have to generate the list only one time in scala spark.

Comment: Are you looking to use Spark features to persist Scala list? Or you are looking to cache Spark Data frame ?

Comment: I am looking for a method which is efficient

Comment: Basically looking to use spark features if there is any

Comment: Let me ask another question. Do you expect it to survive between spark sessions? Or do you just need it persisted for one spark job?

Comment: I want the list to persist in the spark session

Comment: I don't understand. You are getting a scala list back from the function. Just do "val animalList = getAnimalName(df)". And use animalList whenever you need instead of calling the function. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something as below and you can also check the performance using `time` func.
Also find the code explanation inline

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, functions}

object HandleCachedDF {

  var cachedAnimalDF : rdd.RDD[String] = _
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess
    val df = spark.read.json("src/main/resources/hugeTest.json") // Load your Dataframe
    val df1 = time[rdd.RDD[String]] {
      getAnimalName(df)
    }
    val resultList = df1.collect().toList
    val df2 = time{
      getAnimalName(df)
    }
    val resultList1 = df2.collect().toList
    println(resultList.equals(resultList1))
  }

  def getAnimalName(dataFrame: DataFrame): rdd.RDD[String] = {
    if (cachedAnimalDF == null) { // Check if this the first initialization of your dataframe
      cachedAnimalDF = dataFrame.select("animal").
        filter(functions.col("animal").isNotNull && col("animal").notEqual("")).
        rdd.map(r => r.getString(0)).distinct().cache() // Cache your dataframe
    }
    cachedAnimalDF // Return your cached dataframe
  }

  def time[R](block: => R): R = { // COmpute the time taken by function to execute
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
    result
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to persist or cache at this point

```
dataFrame.select("animal").
      filter(col("animal").isNotNull && col("animal").notEqual("")).
      rdd.map(r => r.getString(0)).distinct().persist
```

and then call the function as follow

```
def getAnimalName(dataFrame: DataFrame): List[String] = {
    dataFrame.collect.toList
  }
```

as many times as you need it without repeat the process.
I hope it helps.